# Getting error for command not found in less and shell

Tags: shell, command, localhost

according to less manual,

```
!command Execute the shell command with $SHELL.
```

I have an alias `pbcopy='nc localhost 2224'`

I tested but get

```
!pbcopy
/bin/bash: pbcopy: command not found
!done (press RETURN)
```

What I tried

1. put alias in .bash_profile, .bashrc, .profile, none of them works
2. `!source .bash_profile` in less. not working
3. `!alias pbcopy='nc localhost 2224'`

I really need some help to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

aliases are not commands.

Your shell is likely not loading them.

And if it *is* loading them they aren't available in non-interactive shells by default so they still won't work without you explicitly turning aliases on.

Either create that as a shell *function* or as a shell script in your `$PATH`.

It is also almost certainly the case that each `!cmd` invocation is started in a new shell so you cannot carry assignments, variables, functions, etc. from one to the next.